# Все ли запятые нужны в этом предложении?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

Именно так, каждый день, прожитый без греха в смирении и справедливости,и есть праздник души человека.
Правильно ли стоят запятые?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

С запятыми не всё ясно. Почему после ***именно так*** стоит запятая, какая тут грамматика? Если дальше идет пояснение, раскрытие содержания, то надо сделать паузу и обозначить ее двоеточием.

Но вариант с двоеточием совершенно **не смотрится графически,** тогда,  может быть, дело не в графике, а в стилистике.

Конечно, нужен контекст, без него нет окончательного решения, но и так ясно, что предложение нужно редактировать, так как фактически идет повтор: **именно так, (так) и есть.**

Если речь шла о том, что такое праздник для души, то возможно подойдет такой вариант:

**Но ведь каждый день, прожитый без греха, в смирении и справедливости, — это и есть праздник души для человека.**

**Пояснение:**

Связка ***это и есть*** употреблена в связи с распространенностью определения. Предлог ДЛЯ  исключает повтор беспредложного Р.п.

Answer (score 1):

Думаю, явных ошибок тут нет. Хотя я бы постарался сделать это предложение более выразительным:

**Именно так: каждый день, прожитый без греха, в смирении и справедливости, и есть праздник души человека.**

Скорее всего, "без греха", "в смирении" и "в справедливости" — однородные  обстоятельства.